# T4 template cannot write file (file in use)

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, t4

I have a simple T4 template that writes out a `.cs` file containing an `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`, for the purpose of automatically incrementing the build number.

I have a pre-build event configured to use `TextTransform.exe` to run the template.

This worked fine in previous versions of Visual Studio, but in Visual Studio 2017 (the preview version, if it matters) I get this error on around 50% of builds:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyProj\Properties\BuildIncrement.cs' because it is being used by another process.
```

The only other process I guess that could be using the file is msbuild, but I would have thought it would wait until *after* the pre-build events complete before starting compilation.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: snag process explorer and search for the file handle to see who actually is holding onto it.

Comment: @Will it doesn't find it. I guess whatever is locking it only does so for a short (but critical) time